# How to increase sqflite table row length?

Tags: mysql, database, flutter, sqlite, dart

Devs.!

I've very common but rare problem in `sqlflite` database. As i'm getting large amount of data from server that's why we used [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) for save data locally in database.

But as i mentioned we are getting large amount of data. So, when we retrieve that data from database, we are getting some errors or  can say bugs which is as following,

```
W/CursorWindow(15261): Window is full: requested allocation 1310926 bytes, free space 904042 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
E/SQLiteQuery(15261): exception: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow required Pos=0, totalRows=1; query: SELECT * FROM my_package
```

As solution i found that we are retrieving more than 1 mb sized data from table at single query and  Because of there's limit of 1 MB in sql. we are facing this issue.

So, My question is how do we increase this limit in sql flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to increase CursorWindow size limit as it is mentioned here : [Issue raised in Sqflite having comment saying about limit been unchangeable](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/479#issuecomment-660449943)

Feel free to try any of the suggested solutions in this StackOverflow comment: [various ways to circumvent the issue in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66576751)